# Returning a base64 encoded value when setting a cookie (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, cookies, set, base64, ascii

I am currently trying to see if I can encode a document.cookie to base64 after it has been set. Example code is below

```
function b64EncodeUnicode(str) {
return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g,
    function toSolidBytes(match, p1) {
        return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
}));
}

function setCookie(name,value,maxage,expires,path,domain,secure) {

    document.cookie = name + "=" +escape(value) +
    ( (maxage) ? ";max-age=" + maxage: "") +
    ( (expires) ? ";expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") +
    ( (path) ? ";path=" + path : "") +
    ( (domain) ? ";domain=" + domain : "") +
    ( (secure) ? ";secure" : "");

    return b64EncodeUnicode(document.cookie);
}

setCookie('test',delimitedFAInfo,maxAge,expy,'/','testsite.com','');
```

However it seems whenever I try to print out document.cookie it gives me an unencoded value (_ga=GA1.2.845272544.1516210066; _gid=GA1.2.813051668.1516210066). Was wanting to get some pointers as to what I may be missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please show us the code where you create your cookie ?

Comment: Here, you are never calling setCookie function, where are you calling it ?

Comment: Just added the setCookie, sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is :

```
function setCookie(name,value,maxage,expires,path,domain,secure) {

    document.cookie = name + "=" +escape(value) +
    ( (expires) ? ";expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") +
    ( (maxage) ? ";max-age=" + maxage: "") +
    ( (path) ? ";path=" + path : "") +
    ( (domain) ? ";domain=" + domain : "") +
    ( (secure) ? ";secure" : "");

    return b64EncodeUnicode(document.cookie);
}
```

Working demo : https://codepen.io/andreds/pen/goBVqb

You max-age wasn't at the right place. If I understand, you want to return a base64 of your cookies when you call the function setCookie ?

If you want to base64 encore one of your cookies, you'll have to encode setCookie function parameters before use it into setCookie().

André